# Selenium webscraper keeps shutting down with no error

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, web

Here below I have the code for scraping a site for personal use. But every time I run the script it opens the browser pop-up and closes shortly after with nothing added to the JSON. I also don't see any errors in the console is there something I'm missing or a way to see the stack trace for the issue? Any guidance or input on what I could look at to fix would be greatly appreciated, Thank you!

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import json
import time
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

with open("sportingbet.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump([], f)

def write_json(new_data, filename='sportingbet.json'):
    with open(filename, 'r+') as file:
        file_data = json.load(file)
        file_data.append(new_data)
        file.seek(0)
        json.dump(file_data, file, indent=4)

# Create a new instance of the Chrome driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# Navigate to a website
driver.get("https://sports.sportingbet.com/pt-br/sports/futebol-4/aposta/brasil-33/brasileir%C3%A3o-s%C3%A9rie-a-102838")

buttonPath = '//*[@id="messages-with-overlay"]/div/vn-content-message/div/span'
button = driver.find_element('xpath', buttonPath)
button.click()


index = 1
while True:

    print("in here")
    hometeam = '//*[@id="main-view"]/ms-widget-layout/ms-widget-slot/ms-composable-widget/ms-widget-slot[2]/ms-tabbed-grid-widget/ms-grid/div/ms-event-group[1]/ms-event[1]/div/a/ms-event-detail/ms-event-name/ms-inline-tooltip/div/div[' + str(index) +']/div/div'
    awayteam = '//*[@id="main-view"]/ms-widget-layout/ms-widget-slot/ms-composable-widget/ms-widget-slot[2]/ms-tabbed-grid-widget/ms-grid/div/ms-event-group[1]/ms-event[' + str(index) +']/div/a/ms-event-detail/ms-event-name/ms-inline-tooltip/div/div[2]/div/div'
    homeWin  = '//*[@id="main-view"]/ms-widget-layout/ms-widget-slot/ms-composable-widget/ms-widget-slot[2]/ms-tabbed-grid-widget/ms-grid/div/ms-event-group[1]/ms-event[' + str(index) +']/div/div/ms-option-group[1]/ms-option[1]/ms-event-pick/div/div[2]/ms-font-resizer'
    tie      = '//*[@id="sleague_2417"]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[' + str(index) +']/td[5]/a/span'
    awayWin  = '//*[@id="sleague_2417"]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[' + str(index) +']/td[7]/a/span'

    try:
        # Find the text element using the dynamic XPath
        homeTeamName = driver.find_element('xpath', hometeam)
        awayTeamName = driver.find_element('xpath', awayteam)
        homeWinScore = driver.find_element('xpath', homeWin)
        tieScore = driver.find_element('xpath', tie)
        awayWinScore = driver.find_element('xpath', awayWin)

        write_json({
          "HomeTeam" : homeTeamName.text,
          "AwayTeam" : awayTeamName.text,
          "HomeWin" : homeWinScore.text,
          "Tie" : tieScore.text,
          "AwayWin" : awayWinScore.text
        })
        print(homeTeamName.text)
        index += 1

    except NoSuchElementException:
        # Break the loop if no more elements are found
        break

with open("sportingbet.json", 'r') as file:
    json_data = file.read()

insert_string = "\"sportingbet\"" + ": "
new_json_data = insert_string + json_data

with open("sportingbet.json", 'w') as file:
    file.write(new_json_data)

# Close the browser
driver.quit()
```

Print statments
Double checking Xpaths
Also to note I have a similar setup on other sites and works for them